# How can I fix this "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I wrote this for comparing two arrays and find #||≥|_| :

```
count = 0
for a in range(len(coeffs)):
  for b in range(len(observed_coefficient)):
    if np.abs(coeffs[a]) >= np.abs(observed_coefficient[b]):
      count += 1
print(count)
```

However I get this error because of the if part. How can i fix this?

Comment: Please share your dataframe and the code with expected output.

Comment: try just doing: `count = sum(np.where(np.array(list(map(abs, coeffs))) >= np.array(list(map(abs, observed_coefficient))), 1, 0))` without any loops. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Yo_Chris yep it works, thank you:)